# How to check if an element of an array of pointers is null in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I need to check if an element of an array of pointers is `NULL` or not.
I tried to write the code as following, but the compiler gives me an error.

```
struct Example {
    float number1;
    int number2;
};
typedef struct Example Example;

static Example *array[3] = { NULL }; //inizialized array to NULL

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (array[i] == NULL) {
            /*code*/
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get:

`"error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘Example’ and ‘void *’)"`

referred to the line

```
 if (array[i] == NULL) {
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The `for` loop was originally inside another function that took as parameter the array of pointers.

```
static void fun(Example *array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (array[i] == NULL) {
            /*code*/
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But it keeps giving me the same error, despite the fact that the type is actually `Example*` and not `Example`.
Instead, if I write `Example** array` as parameter, it accepts the code and doesn't give me any error.

```
static void fun (Example **array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (array[i] == NULL) {
            /*code*/
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why does the compiler wants `Example**` and not `Example*` ?

**FULL CODE**

Here's the full code, in 2 files: **file.c** and **file.h**.

**file.h**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct Example {
    float number1;
    int number2;
};
typedef struct Example Example;
```

**file.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "file.h"

static Example *array[3] = { NULL }; //inizialized array to NULL
static void fun(Example *);

static void fun(Example *array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (array[i] == NULL) {
            /*code*/
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    fun(array);
    return 0;
}
```

ERROR:

```
gcc -c file.c -std=c11 -Wall
file.c: In function ‘fun’:
file.c:10:28: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘Example’ and ‘void *’)
   10 |                if(array[i] == NULL){
      |                   ~~~~~~~~ ^~
      |                        |
      |                        Example
file.c: In function ‘main’:
file.c:20:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fun’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   20 |     fun(array);
      |         ^~~~~
      |         |
      |         Example **
file.c:8:26: note: expected ‘Example *’ but argument is of type ‘Example **’
    8 | static void fun(Example* array){
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Comment: Maybe you are using a C++ compiler? [Hint: dont!]

Comment: Please show http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- the code as is compiles without warnings.

Comment: How are you compiling this? Using a C++ compiler? Your code is correct C. You may have intentionally or unintentionally used used a C++ compiler, if it's intentionally stop doing so and if it's unintentionally, correct your mistake.

Comment: There is a missmatch between the error message and the code you are showing. `array[i]` is of type  `Example *`, but the error message claims that it is of type `Example`

Comment: Yes, I'm using a C compiler.
I updated the question for more details, I really don't get what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should be aware that in your program, you have two distinct variables with the name `array`:

1. The global variable of that name.
2. The local variable (function parameter) of the function `fun`.

Inside the function `fun`, the local variable `array` will shadow the global variable of the same name, which means that when you write `array` inside that function, you will be referring to the local variable, not the global variable. To prevent any confusion, you may want to use different names for both variables.

The compiler is complaining about the following line:

```
if(array[i] == NULL){
```

As previously stated, using the identifier `array` inside the function `fun` will refer to the function parameter, not the global variable.

In the function definition of `fun`, you defined the type of the function parameter `array` to be `Example *`. Therefore, dereferencing this type using `array[i]` will give you a variable of type `Example`. This means that in `array[i] == NULL`, you are attempting to compare a `struct Example` with the value `NULL`. This does not make sense, and is also the reason why are you getting the compiler error.

Instead of defining the function parameter `array` to be of type `Example*`, you probably want it to be of type `Example**`, because you want it to point to the first element of the array, which is itself a pointer to a `struct Example`. In other words, you want the function parameter to be a pointer to a pointer. Therefore, you should also declare it as such:

```
static void fun( Example **array ){
```

Or maybe better:

```
static void fun( Example *array[] ){
```

Both of these lines are equivalent as far as the compiler is concerned, but the second line is maybe better, as it makes clear that the pointer is not pointing to a single variable, but rather to an array.

The expression `array[i] == NULL` now makes sense, as it will now compare an `Entity*` with `NULL`.

After applying this change to the function definition of `fun`, and after also applying it to the forward declaration of the function, your code will compile cleanly.